# What does the "pod install" command do on Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, heroku, zsh

I was watching a video on creating an iOS App using Xcode and Heroku. The following command was typed in Z shell `zsh`:

```
pod install
```

What does this do and what is it used for? A simple overview would be sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It installs the dependencies as specified by the pod file in the Xcode project folder. See [cocoapods.org](http://cocoapods.org) for details.

Comment: That's nice! I didn't realise there were so many helpful [custom controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls) that I can use. What's your experience of using them? are they well maintained across iOS versions?

Comment: CocoaControls? It's a listing of items from github, so it's a mixed bag in terms of quality.

Answer (score 0):

#### To expand Wain's answer:

`pod install` installs all listed pods in `Podfile`. If your using React Native it can link your dependencies with react-native. This can fix linking issues with dependencies. You can also edit the `Podfile` to manually import pods. All pods will be moved to a `Pods` directory.